# Camel ProducerTemplate.getBody(Class<T>) Json to Pojo is always returning null

Tags: jakarta-ee, apache-camel

I have a producer template that invokes an Http4 end point. How can I convert the response in to Pojo? Only convert to String is working, but not convert to Pojo using producerTemplate.getBody(Class).

```
Map<String, Object> headers = new HashMap<>();
headers.put(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, GET);

//This is working, I can see the response
String responseBody = producerTemplate.getBody(String.class);

//This not working working, always return null
Foo responseBody = producerTemplate.getBody(Foo.class);
```

Sample Foo Json:

```
{
"name":"juan",
"age": 12
}
```

Foo.java

```
public class Foo {
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an evolution for camel 2.17 on the jackson converter, with [CAMEL-9583](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-9583). With this change, you will be able to enable a "fallback converter" using Jackson by setting these property in the context :

```
context.getProperties().put(JacksonConstants.ENABLE_TYPE_CONVERTER, "true");
context.getProperties().put(JacksonConstants.TYPE_CONVERTER_TO_POJO, "true");
```

Camel will then try to use Jackson to convert the message to your pojo class.

With the current version (2.16), you can create an explicit converter for your pojo :

```
@Converter
public FooConverter {

  private static final ObjectMapper MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();

  @Converter
  public static Foo fromString(String message) {
    return MAPPER.readValue(message, Foo.class);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Jackson like so:

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
// [...]
ObjectMapper json = new ObjectMapper();
Foo foo = json.readValue(producerTemplate.getBody(String.class), Foo.class);
```

I am not aware of a way to inject a [json data format](http://camel.apache.org/json.html) for un-marshalling directly into a producer template.

Of course you can use any other JSON library if you choose to do so.